CognitoIdentityCredentials is not authorized to perform: execute-api:Invoke on resource
I have a role MyRole that is associated to a user account. I attached to that role the MyRolePolicy policy:
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:myRegion:1111111111:myApiID/dev/*/POST/feedback"
        }

When a user calls the endpoint (REST API GATEWAY), i get the error:
User: arn:aws:sts::1111111111:assumed-role/myRole/CognitoIdentityCredentials is not authorized to perform: execute-api:Invoke on resource: arn:aws:execute-api:myRegion:********1111:myApiID/dev/POST/myApiName/feedback\

Is something wrong with my policy?
